# Role guard sometimes allows entry into secured components on localhost

Tags: angular, typescript, authorization, roles, guard

My RoleGuard looks like this:

```
import { CanLoad, Route } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../_services";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RoleGuard implements CanLoad {

    constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

    canLoad(route: Route) {
        let authorities = route.data.roles;
        if (this.authService.hasAnyRole(authorities)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and my methods in authService:

```
 hasAnyRole(roles: string[]): boolean {
        for (let i = 0; i <= roles.length; i++) {
            if (this.hasRole(roles[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    hasRole(role: string): boolean {
        let authorities = this.getAuthority();
        return authorities.findIndex(a => a === role) > -1;
    }
```

app.routing.ts :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        canActivate: [NoAuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'password',
        component: PasswordComponent,
        canActivate: [NoAuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'change-password',
        component: ChangePasswordComponent,
        canActivate: [ChangePasswordGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'reset-password',
        component: ResetPasswordComponent,
        canActivate: [ResetPasswordGuard],
        resolve: {
            recoverPassword: ResetPasswordGuard
        }
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'users',
                loadChildren: '../app/users/users.module#UsersModule',
                canLoad: [RoleGuard],
                data: { roles: ['AK.W.1'] }
            },
            {
                path: 'products',
                loadChildren: '../app/products/products.module#ProductsModule',
                canLoad: [RoleGuard],
                data: { roles: ['AK.W.1', 'AK.W.2'] }
            },
            {
                path: 'codes',
                loadChildren: '../app/codes/codes.module#CodesModule',
                canLoad: [RoleGuard],
                data: { roles: ['AK.W.1', 'AK.W.2'] }
            },
            {
                path: 'reports',
                loadChildren: '../app/reports/reports.module#ReportsModule',
                canLoad: [RoleGuard],
                data: { roles: ['AK.W.1','AK.W.2','AK.W.3'] }
            }
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

User authorized roles for components are provided in path's data and checked in AuthorizationService. Methods get user's roles from token and nextable compare them with roles provided in path's data. 
The problem is guard doesn't work properly. Sometimes it allows unauthorized users to let in secured components on localhost mostly after first login when app is served. Could you indicate me what's wrong with my guard?

Comment: Does it make any API call or Asynchronous task to check for the Role ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be with `CanLoad`. `CanLoad` Gaurd protects a `module` to be loaded but once `module` is loaded then `CanLoad` guard does nothing.

For example, lets say A user logged in application and he navigates to some Module. After that he click on logout. Now if user wants he will be able to navigate to same module since the it was loaded already.

So if you want to protect your application, the best would be to use `CanActivate`.

> Add `CanActivate` into your RoleGaurd

```
import { CanLoad, CanActivate, Route,Router,
 ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from "../_services";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RoleGuard implements CanLoad, CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService,private router: Router) { }

    canLoad(route: Route) {
        let authorities = route.data.roles;
        if (this.authService.hasAnyRole(authorities)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let authorities = route.data.roles;
        if (this.authService.hasAnyRole(authorities)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
     }

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I used both canLoad and canActivate which prevent unauthorized user to load module and get into secured component.